# thingsboard mqtt message lenght limited to 100 bytes?

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I am trying to send several variables trough mqtt messages, but the messages is not going trough when I send more that 100 bytes, is there a limit in the thingsboard mqtt broker? Because for what I've seen mqtt has payload limits much higher than 100 bytes.
If it is the case, is it configurable?
Thanks

Comment: Commit log for thingsboard/application (Commit 44a1fa2911b1f51830c97ea98e4c221a67c4e2ad) adds "ReconnectDelay and MaxBytesInMessage configurable" to the mqtt broker. Supporting link [thingsboard commit](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/commit/44a1fa2911b1f51830c97ea98e4c221a67c4e2ad)

Comment: Paul, can you explain me a bit more what you mean with this? When can I find that file? If the max bytes size is around 8000 why are my messages not being sent when I reach 100 characters?

Comment: A bit old question, but anyway, what are you using for sending messages to TB service? It could be that the limitation is on the sending, not on the receiving side. In my case I was using ESP8666 with PubSubClient, which has 128 bytes send limit by default